# What is the best way to consume a WebSocket API for PowerBI via OracleDB?

Tags: oracle, websocket, powerbi, talend

My data source is a WebSocket API that provides a channel to listen to.
The final destination is for use in PowerBI for near Real-Time reporting.
Ideally I need to first write this data to an Oracle DB for data transformation before using DirectQuery in PowerBI.
Also, have Talend at my disposal for ETL.

What would be the best practice solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best practice, but here's how I would do it with Talend:

```
tRESTClient (API) --> format/extract data (JSON, XML, etcc.) --> tDBOutput (Oracle)
```

Afterwards, depending on the amount of data to be processed, we could do a first step of collecting the data and saving it in DB.
In a second step, we prepare either with Talend in new tables or views in DB, the desired data for PowerBI